# Applying a function to subsets of data in a data frame using a moving window in R

Tags: r, window, dataframe, distance, subset

I would like to create a script that applies a function to subsets of spatial points throughout a data frame using a moving window.

Given a data matrix containing a column with latitude positions and a column with longitude positions, I would like to obtain a measure of sinuosity for every 5 consecutive locations in my overall dataset (i.e. apply the function to every set of 5 locations from start to end). Sinuosity is the ratio of the actual distance moved along a series of points to the straight-line distance moved between the start and end points.

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(IndexNo = 1:13, Latitude = c(52.363205, 52.640715, 
52.940366, 53.267749, 53.512608, 53.53215, 53.536443, 53.553523, 
53.546862, 53.55095, 53.571766, 53.587558, 53.592084), Longitude = c(3.433247, 
3.305727, 3.103194, 2.973257, 2.966621, 3.013587, 3.002674, 3.004011, 
2.98778, 2.995589, 3.004867, 3.003511, 2.999092)), .Names = c("IndexNo", "Latitude", "Longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names=c(NA,-13L))
```

Desired output:

```
IndexNo       Latitude  Longitude   Sinuosity
1             52.36321  3.433247    NA
2             52.64072  3.305727    1.0085
3             52.94037  3.103194    1.0085
4             53.26775  2.973257    1.0085
5             53.51261  2.966621    1.0085
6             53.53215  3.013587    1.9392
7             53.53644  3.002674    1.9392
8             53.55352  3.004011    1.9392
9             53.54686  2.987780    1.9392
10            53.55095  2.995589    1.0669
11            53.57177  3.004867    1.0669
12            53.58756  3.003511    1.0669
13            53.59208  2.999092    1.0669
```

Initial attempt (at code for calculating sinuosity for a single section of 5 locations):

```
# To create a subset of the first 5 locations in the data frame
subset<- bird[1:5, c("Latitude", "Longitude","IndexNo")]
library(trip)

# To calculate the straight-line distance between the beginning and end point of a 5-point sequence
straightd<- trackDistance(subset[1,2], subset[1,1], subset[5,2], subset[5,1], longlat=TRUE)

# To calculate the distance between each pair of consecutive points (for a 5-point sequence)
d1<- trackDistance(subset[1,2], subset[1,1], subset[2,2], subset[2,1], longlat=TRUE)
d2<- trackDistance(subset[2,2], subset[2,1], subset[3,2], subset[3,1], longlat=TRUE)
d3<- trackDistance(subset[3,2], subset[3,1], subset[4,2], subset[4,1], longlat=TRUE)
d4<- trackDistance(subset[4,2], subset[4,1], subset[5,2], subset[5,1], longlat=TRUE)
# To return the actual distance between the beginning and end point of a 5-point sequence
actd<- sum(d1,d2,d3,d4)

# Function to calcualte the sinuosity (ratio between the actual distance and the straight-line distance)
sinuosity <- function (x, y) {
  x/y
}
new <- sinuosity(actd, straightd)

# To add a sinuosity column to the 5 rows of locations on which the sinuosity index was measured
subset$Sinuosity <- rep(new, nrow(subset))
```

Comment: That's a long question but going mainly by your output, why don't you set up a loop over `i = seq(1,30, by = 5)` and use `i, i+1,...i+4` in your row subscripts?

Comment: @ Codoremifa: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I would not know how to go about doing this.I am still learning. Could you provide an example? I plan to apply this code to a number of data frames of different sizes, so it would be better not to have to change the seq each time. Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of rows in your actual dataset divisible by five?  In your example there are 13 rows.  What would you do with the last 3 rows?

Comment: @ aosmith: I have edited the example to show the desired output in full. My data frames are not necessarily divisible by 5 but it is fine if there is no output for the final few rows. As the sinuosity function relates to distances between two points, I would like the sinuosity value to appear in the row containing the second point in each case (as shown in the example). As such the first row in the data frame will be empty and every 5th row will be used as both the first and last point in the 5-location subset before and after. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, there are lots of ways to go.  I think you could do this with a series of loops like @Codoremifa showed you or with some handy add-on packages such as `data.table` that @RInatM walked you through.  I made an example working with the `sapply` function to loop through the data.

First, I calculated the distance between each pair of points in sequence for the whole dataset based on your code.  I used `with` to avoid having to use dollar sign notation or the extract function `[`.  You can see the vector output `pairdist` is 1 unit shorter than the number of rows in the dataset.

```
pairdist = sapply(2:nrow(bird), function(x) with(bird, trackDistance(Longitude[x-1], Latitude[x-1], 
                                 Longitude[x], Latitude[x], longlat=TRUE) ))
```

Then I go through a similar step to add up each group of four of the pairs of distance to get the measure of the total distance.  You can see this only has three values for your example dataset, as it should.

```
totdist= sapply(seq(1,length(pairdist)-3, by = 4), function(x) sum(pairdist[x:(x+3)]))
```

Next calculate the straightline distance between the first and fifth points, fifth and ninth points, etc.

```
straight = sapply(seq(1, nrow(bird)-4, by = 4), function(x) with(bird,trackDistance(Longitude[x],
                                                                    Latitude[x], 
                                 Longitude[x+4], Latitude[x+4], longlat=TRUE) ))
```

In the end you want to calculate the ratio and add it back to the original dataset with an NA for the first point and the same value for every set of four points after that.  To make this more generalizable to datasets of various lengths I pad the end with NA if needed.  The code for that might look confusing, but it was just some math to calculate how much padding would be needed based on how you group your points together.

```
bird$Sinuosity = c(NA, rep(totdist/straight, each = 4), 
                rep(NA, length(pairdist)-4*floor(length(pairdist)/4)))
```

Comment: @ aosmith: Thank you for the answer. Very helpful. I really like the sapply method. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set up your loop along the following lines -

```
for(i in seq(1,(dim(df)[1]), by = 4)
{
subset<- bird[i:(i+4), c("Latitude", "Longitude","IndexNo")]
straightd<- trackDistance(subset[i,(i+1)], subset[i,i], subset[(i+4),(i+1)], subset[(i+4),i], longlat=TRUE)
# etc.
}
```

Compare it to the code you posted and you should see what's happening. This is only a guide ubt you should be able to extrapolate this logic to the rest of your function.

Comment: @ Codoremifa: thanks for the example. A very helpful guide. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You chose a good caption and had an interesting problem, but overloaded it too much with details (make your question useful to others). As I understand, you need to

1. perform pairwise operation between table rows (in your case - distance)
2. collapse the result of this operation using some condition (neighbor points)
3. repeat it for many elements (for each point)

I'm a great fun of [data.table package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf),  so here is my (a bit general and suboptimal) solution

0) merge data table with itself and calculate distance between each pair

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt[, k := 1], k)
dt2 <- merge(dt, dt, allow.cartesian = T]
```

k is an artificial index to get full crossjoin (which in your case excessive, but simple)

1) calculate distance

```
dt2[IndexNo != IndexNo.1
   , dist := trackDistance(Longitude, Latitude, Longitude.1, Latitude.1
   , longlat = T) ]
```

2) apply your condition (summarize distance across neighbor points)

```
sinuosity <- function(start, end) {
  long.dist <- dt2[IndexNo %in% c(start:end) & IndexNo.1 %in% c(start:end) 
                                             & IndexNo == IndexNo.1 - 1
                  , sum(dist, na.rm = T) ]
  short.dist <- dt2[IndexNo == start & IndexNo.1 == end, dist]
  res <- long.dist/short.dist
  return(res)
}
```

3) repeat for each point

```
dt2[IndexNo > IndexNo.1 - 5 & IndexNo <= IndexNo.1
    ,  list(Latitude, Longitude, sinuosity(IndexNo, IndexNo + 4))
    , by = c("IndexNo", "IndexNo.1")]
```

gives what (I guess) you wanted

```
    IndexNo IndexNo.1 Latitude Longitude       V3
 1:       1         1 52.36321  3.433247 1.008512
 2:       1         2 52.36321  3.433247 1.008512
 3:       1         3 52.36321  3.433247 1.008512
 4:       1         4 52.36321  3.433247 1.008512
 5:       1         5 52.36321  3.433247 1.008512
 6:       2         2 52.64072  3.305727 1.033964
 7:       2         3 52.64072  3.305727 1.033964
 8:       2         4 52.64072  3.305727 1.033964
 ......
```

I recommend to spend some time to get acquainted with `data.table`, it can save you a lot of time later. Also, for your particular case, if you have large table (> 1000 rows), you should avoid full crossjoin and merge dt with itself on IndexNo == IndexNo - 1

Comment: @ RlnatM: Thanks also for this extensive example, which will work brilliantly once I sort the crossjoin options. data.table seems to be a very useful package. I will explore it! Many thanks.